# map routing on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, mapkit

I'm developing an application which can view map, geocoding, routing on iOS. 
I've done something like this before on Android (I've used Google map API, google direction API, google geocoding)
How to do that on iOS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the [documentation found here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/) will give you a good starting place.